# How to calculate vehicle RPM using data from the iPhone GPS?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, gps

I was wondering if there was a way to calculate the rpm of a moving vehicle using data from the GPS.

I realize that I could take the speed from the GPS, let's say 20 m/s, multiply by 60 to get 1200 m/min, then I could take the circumference of the wheel, let's say 1.5m, and I get:

RPM = 1200/1.5 = 800 Revolutions Per Minute.

This means that I need to be going at a speed of 270 km/h just to get to an RPM of 3000. (I guess this is the tire RPM and not the engine RPM)

Now that doesn't seem to be the same thing that would be displayed in a vehicle, so I was wondering if there was another way to get the RPM that would be displayed in a vehicle.

P.S. I'm asking because I've seen apps in the app store that have an RPM gauge that goes all the way to 7000 RPM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the RPM the way you describe, but you will need a lot of detailed information about the specific car you are in, including the gear box ratio of each gear, the tyres, etc.

Check out this page on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gear_ratio) for details

Comment: You'd also have to know what gear the car is in. You can be in one of several gears at most velocities ;)

Comment: ...or in neutral running down a hill :-)

Comment: assuming i can ask the user to input their car's gear ratios (they seem to be documented for each car) how would I determine what gear the car is in?

Comment: You would need to ask the user, or alternatively implement some sort of telepathic algorithm - whichever is easiest

Answer (score 1):

Determining engine RPMs requires you to know the gear ratio of the gear the vehicle is currently using. Obviously this is not something you will know with GPS data alone.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought -- maybe the other apps are using the microphone to analyze the frequency
of the engine noise?   That seems like the only way you'd be able to do it without
knowing gear ratios and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OBDII interface to obtain the RPM information direct from the engine's ECU device

Answer (score -3):

- 800 RPM = 20M/s = 72 KMPH
- 3000 RPM is 3000/8000 = 3.75 times = 72 * 3.75 = 270 KMPH

Now, everything seems to be perfectly Logical.

Now, What is your problem???